# bzip2 - Broken pipe

Tags: bash

I have the following code in my shell script:

```
bzip2 -dc $filename | head -10 > $output
```

Sometimes I'm getting this error (debug output enabled):

```
+ head -10
+ bzip2 -dc mylog.bz2

bzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
bzip2: Broken pipe
        Input file = mylog.bz2, output file = (stdout)
```

It looks like `head` command is exiting abruptly and `bzip2` receives SIGPIPE.
What can I do with this? I need to be sure that first 10 lines will be in the `$output` file no matter what. There is no guarantee that this is always the case if one of the processes fails miserably I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The `bzip` command will fail when the `head` command quits after having outputted its lines.  There is no data loss; the `head` command has done its job.

If you are concerned about this, you may replace the call to `head` with a `sed` script that does the same thing:

```
bzip -dc "$filename" | sed -n '1,10p' >"$output"
```

This `sed` script will read all the data from the pipe but not quit when done with line 10.

Comment: Thanks for your response, maybe I should leave everything as is. Unfortunately it's impossible to use `sed` in this case, my file is way too big. Decompression takes about ten minutes.

Comment: @Lazin Then you're best off with using the pipeline as is, yes. Just redirect errors to the bit-bucket if you don't want to see them.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like head command is exiting abruptly and bzip2 receives SIGPIPE.

What do you expect `head` does? It reads as much from the input as it's configured to output, then shuts down. This is pretty much *by design*.

Also:

> ```
> head -10
> ```

My version of `head` expects something that's more like

```
head -n10
```

Comment: There is no difference between `head -10` and `head -n10` AFAIK. Yes `head` does what it does but in correct way (usually) without any errors. This error occurs in production environment and I can't reproduce it so far.

Comment: @Lazin at the very least, for my version of `head`, the non-`-n` version doesn't appear in the docs; but yes, it works.

Comment: @Lazin the difference between `-10` and `-n 10` is that the latter is in the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/head.html), so is more likely to be portable across systems.

Comment: The `-10` form is also in POSIX, but marked as deprecated. It is likely supported by many implementations of `head` but should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch to `-n10` form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` for avoiding empty content to the `head` from the pipe which could be the cause for `SIGPIPE`. This way even if `bzip2` doesn't provide any output you wouldn't be seeing any errors.

```
bzip2 -dc $filename | xargs -r head -10 > $output
```

where the option `-r` says

```
 -r     If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
```

Comment: What did you mean by "empty content"? Empty file or empty lines? How this can cause `SIGPIPE`?

Comment: @Lazin: Sorry for being vague, with the `xargs` option even if you don't have any output piped from `bzip2` to `head`, the command won't fail. In a way head will work only if it has content

Comment: But in my case it is `bzip2` the one who fails. Not the `head`. And this small script works even if input file is empty. If input file is corrupted or empty (not empty archive but 0-size file) there will be other error, corruption will be detected.